# How to understand this scala code?

Tags: scala, traits

the scala code:

```
trait Action{
    def doAction
}

trait BeforeAfterOfAction extends Action{
    abstract override def doAction: Unit ={
        println("before")
        super.doAction
        println("after")
    }
}

class Work extends Action{
    override def doAction = println("working....")
}
object Test{
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val work = new Work with BeforeAfterOfAction
        work.doAction
    }
}
```

the result is:

```
before
working....
after
```

I think it shoud print "`working....`" only, but why not?

Can you explain process detail?

Comment: You explicitly Mixed the trait in, that's why your method gets overridden.

Comment: Can you expain order of executing detail?

Comment: The `abstract` method in your "stackable" trait provides executable behaviour - that is probably the bit you were misunderstanding ie. `abstract override def doAction` will get executed before `Work`'s version. In addition to Sudhir's reference this other resource from Artima also does a pretty good job of explaining the pattern you have implemented here - http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `new Work with BeforeAfterOfAction`, you are using *stack-able behavior* of traits. Excerpt from [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/):

> Traits let you modify the methods of a class, and they do so in a way
>   that allows you to stack those modifications with each other.

You can read it [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.5) in detail.

**EDIT**

To explain it further, when you type:

```
new Work with BeforeAfterOfAction
```

You are actually creating a mixin which is equivalent to below class definition:

```
class MyWork extends Work with BeforeAfterOfAction
```

Now the linearization for `MyWork` class will be like:

```
MyWork -> BeforeAfterOfAction -> Work -> Action -> AnyRef -> Any
```

When you invoke `new MyWork().doAction` (where `new MyWork()` is equivalent to `new Work with BeforeAfterOfAction`), it invokes `doAction` from `BeforeAfterOfAction`, as `MyWork` does not have `doAction` method.

Interesting part comes when `super.doAction` is encountered in `BeforeAfterOfAction`'s `doAction`. When `super` is encountered, `doAction` from the first right in the linearization is picked. Which in this case is `doAction` from `Work`. Hence you see output like:

```
before
working....
after
```

You can read more about linearization from [this](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.6) link.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
val x = new A with B with C
x.meth()
```

This instance of `x` is a mix of traits (or classes) `A`, `B`, and `C`.  When the method `meth()` is invoked, the compiler will first look in `C` to see if it defines that method.  If it's not found then it will look in `B`, and finally in `A`.

In your example:

```
val work = new Work with BeforeAfterOfAction
work.doAction
```

...the method `doAction` is found in `BeforeAfterOfAction`, so that's the one that gets executed.  But in that method is the call to `super.doAction`.  What is the super-class of `BeforeAfterOfAction`?  It is whatever came before it when the traits were mixed.

Therefore, the compiler first looks at `Work` to see if a `doAction` method is defined there.  Since it is, that's what gets executed.